# Install specific version of apt package for specific ubuntu version

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt

I want to install package `foo` version `1234` in a docker container. I prefer this to the latest version, as it will always work the same way.

So my Dockerfile has this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y foo=1234
```

But the base image is [`mongodb:4.0.2`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/0d81416797611e471ec456ec99306c987a224418/4.0/Dockerfile#L1), which is layered on Ubuntu xenial.

When I build the image, the apt install fails because it cannot find that version. I think xenial doesn't support that version.

So how do I find the latest supported version of a package `foo` on xenial? If I run `apt policy foo` it shows me the latest for the ubuntu I'm using (bionic), not for xenial.

Comment: I'm looking for a programmatic way to do this. But there is a dirty way to do this too: run the container, shell into it, and run `apt-get update && apt-cache policy foo` to show the latest for that ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package at stake is, say, `rlwrap`, you could just take a look at the webpage https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rlwrap

But if you want a proper way to get this version info programatically, you can rely on the [Launchpad API](https://help.launchpad.net/API/), which comes with an official [API client implemented as a Python library](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib).

Otherwise, you can directly query the API with tools such as `curl` and `jq` (to parse the retrieved JSON data):

```
$ curl -fsSL "https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/ubuntu/+archive/primary?ws.op=getPublishedSources&source_name=rlwrap&exact_match=true&distro_series=https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/ubuntu/xenial" \
  | jq --raw-output ".entries | .[0] | .source_package_version"

→ 0.41-1build1
```

As mentioned in this [Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620956/does-packages-ubuntu-com-provide-a-search-api), a similar API exists for Debian as well.